# Automatically Click link on page after loading, based on previous link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation menu which is made up of several dropdowns. The menu is a bootstrap navigation menu. Each link goes to the same page. The next page "/page" has several other links. When the user clicks on the nav link and the next page is loaded i want it to automatically click a link on that page with a specific href attribute. Here is what i got so far but no lucky...

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).on('click', '.link-1', function(){ 
 $('a[href="#1485519100309"]').click(); 
 });
```

**HTML Part of the bootsrap NavBar**

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http:/#">Title<span class="caret">
</span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
    <a class="link-1" href="http://myurlhere/page">Tab Link 1</a>
   </li>
  <li>
  <a class="link-2" href="http://myurlhere/page">Tab Link 2</a>
</li>
 <li>
  <a class="link-3" href="http://myurlhere/page">Tab Link 3</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="link-4" href="http://myurlhere/page">Tab Link 4</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: The document tree element with class '.experience' is not included in your example code, I would recommend including all relevant code in order for anyone to be able to answer your question. Are you getting any errors? That said, try adding an "a" in your .click() call - `$('a[href="#12341234123"]').click(); `

Comment: That is working, however it only works once i am on that /page already. If i am on another page lets say the home page and i click on the nav dropdown it still goes to /page but it does not click on the link.

Comment: That's odd. When/where are you including the jQuery script? maybe encapsulate the code in `$(document).ready(function(){your code here});`

Comment: Hi, I am already doing that ^^! can we continue in chat for 2 seconds? Thanks

Comment: I actually don't know how to enter chat on this website lol, if you can figure out how to invite me sure

Comment: xD the only way i know is to  post comment here until 7/8  are reached then it says invite to chat...

Answer (score 0):

Using class:

```
$(".link-1").trigger('click');
```

or

```
$("a[href='href-link']").trigger('click');
```

Comment: But this only triggers if im already on that page, not if im in another page say the home page.

Comment: @user1673498 You can't trigger something like a click on another page of you are on a different page because its not in the DOM. Events can only be triggered on elements that are currently in the DOM. Unless you just redirect to that link.

Comment: Or @user1673498 Then you will have to do in the ```$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href='href-link']").trigger('click');
});```